# Apache Spark in yarn-cluster mode is throwing Hadoop FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to execute my Spark job in yarn-cluster mode. It is working fine with standalone and yarn-client mode, but in cluster mode it is throwing `FileAlreadyExistsException` at `pairs.saveAsTextFile(output);`

Here is my implementation of job:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LIM Spark PolygonFilter").setMaster(master);  
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);            
        Broadcast<IGeometry> boundryBroadCaster = broadcastBoundry(javaSparkContext, boundaryPath);         
        JavaRDD<String> file = javaSparkContext.textFile(input);//.cache();     
        JavaRDD<String> pairs = file.filter(new FilterFunction(params , boundryBroadCaster));
        pairs.saveAsTextFile(output);
```

As per logs, it works for one node and after that it start throwing this exception for rest of all nodes.

Can someone please help me to fix it ... ? Thanks.

Comment: After disabling output spec it is working: (`spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs=true`). And after fixing FileAlreadyExistsException, job was failing for Channel closed, and it was fixed with parameter `fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache = true`.
I found many opened bugs with these exceptions. And i found these workarounds from these bugs. I don't know is it a correct behavior or am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After disabling output spec it is working: (spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs=true).

It looks like a feature of Hadoop to notify user that the specified output directory is already has some data and it will be lost if you will use same directory for next iteration of this job.

In my application i provided an extra parameter for job - -overwrite, and we are using it like this:

`spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs = value of overwrite flag`

If user want to overwrite existing output than he can provide value of "overwrite" flag as true.